# Need a LINQ query to find string items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<NameClass>` that stores a collection of `NameClass` items with a property called `Name` in the class. What I'm trying to do is write a Linq query that will pull all the names that start with `Jones`, but only if there are 3 or more occurrences. For example, if my list had the following items:

```
Name
-----------
Jones
Jonestown
Smith
Hector
Jones
Smith
Smith
```

I am looking for a C# function that I can call like this:

```
GetNames("Jones");
```

And it should return:

```
Jones
Jonestown
Jones
```

And if I run this:

```
GetNames("Smith");
```

It should return:

```
Smith
Smith
Smith
```

And if I run this:

```
GetNames("Hector");
```

It should return nothing since `Hector` isn't in the list 3 or more times.

Any help writing this LINQ query would be appreciated!

Comment: If this is homework, please tag with "homework."

Comment: No offense to the OP, but he certainly doesn't look like a school kid from the pic ;-)

Comment: There's lots of homework in the world. The way the question is stated looks more like an academic assignment than real world. Sometimes it's hard to tell when someone is asking for homework help vs. providing an easy-to-understand scenario.  With 5300 reputation from OP, I should've known better, but I typed the comment prior to looking at @icemanind's rep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string searchString = "Jones";
string lowerSS = searchString.ToLower();

List<NameClass> nameClasses; 

var results = nameClasses.Where(nc => nc.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(lowerSS));

if(results != null && results.Count() >= 3)
{
    return results;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I like the way you get results. Maybe do something like: return results.Count >= 3 ? results: new List<NamesClass>(); instead of the if-else

Comment: When you've got too many things going on- like checking to see if results could be null as well- then putting everything in one line makes things less readable. We often deal with huge code bases, being more verbose helps. Returning an empty list is just a waste of resources and I'd rather condition myself to expect 'null' results, because it's a better practice in general. ? operator definitely has its place and I use it often.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this, aren't you?

```
public static IEnumerable<NameClass> GetNames(IEnumerable<NameClass> names, String name, int minCount)
{
    var matchingNames = names.Where(n => n.Name.StartsWith(name));
    if (matchingNames.Count() >= minCount)
    {
        return matchingNames.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

var jones = GetNames(names, "Jones", 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
public void GetNames(string pattern)
{
    var q = from n in names
        where n.Name.StartsWith(pattern)
        select n;

    if (q.Count() >= 3)
        return q.ToList();
    else
        return new List<NameClass>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<NameClass> GetNames(string s, List<NameClass> list)
{
    var filtered = list.Where(l => l.Name.StartsWith(s));
    return filtered.Count() >= 3 ? filtered : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need it all in one query this extension method should do it:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetNames(this IEnumerable<string> list, string prefix, int minOccurences)
{
    var res = list.Where(x => x.StartsWith(prefix));
    return res.Count() >= minOccurences ? res : new string[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A "one liner":

```
public string[] GetNames(MyClass[] list, string prefix)
{
    return list
        .Where(item => 
            item.Name.StartsWith(prefix) && 
            list.Count(temp => temp.Name.StartsWith(prefix)) > 2)
        .Select(l => l.Name)
        .ToArray();
}
```